# How to implement Search function using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Here I write code where all persons names comes from Facebook API, and it is showing on lightbox. Now I want to implement search functionality using JavaScript/jQuery. Can you help me? How should I implement search function?

Invite Facebook Friend
    
    
    
     James 
    
    
    
    
    
    Alan 
    
    
    
    
    
     Mathew

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
    var g = $(this).val();
    $(".fbbox .fix label").each( function() {
        var s = $(this).text();
        if (s.indexOf(g)!=-1) {
            $(this).parent().parent().show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztaz6/1/)

or Better Way:

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".fbbox .fix label").each(function() {
        var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        $(this).closest('.fbbox')[ s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
    });
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ztaz6/2/)

Comment: sorry man the code i gave you, don't search by clicking search button but do it automatically!

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but I would also make it case insensitive: `var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();` and `var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase()` - [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ztaz6/2/)

Comment: @Mottie I add the link of your fiddle also ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Jquery**

```
​  $(document).ready(function(){

   var search = $("#search-criteria");
   var items  = $(".fbbox");

   $("#search").on("click", function(e){

        var v = search.val().toLowerCase();
       if(v == "") { 
           items.show();
           return;
       }
        $.each(items, function(){
            var it = $(this);
            var lb = it.find("label").text().toLowerCase();
            if(lb.indexOf(v) == -1) 
                 it.hide();
        });
    });        
});​
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/C3PEc/2/

Comment: So... use jQuery just because of `indexOf`, which you don't need jQuery for?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, use jquery for events and each function.

Comment: This breaks when you search for "fb 1" then change to "fb 3"... it won't unhide "fb 3". Change this: `if (lb.indexOf(v) == -1) { it.hide(); } else { it.show(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use indexOf method:

```
var text ="some name";
var search = "some";

if (text.indexOf(search)!=-1) {

    // do someting with found item

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression instead of `indexOf` as it may not work in IE7/IE8
and using regular expression you will can also use the 'i' modifier to make the search case insensitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const cities = ['Paris', 'Pattaya', 'New York'];
const searchedItem = 'Pa';
const filteredCities = cities.filter((city) => city.includes(searchedItem));
```