# How to clear text id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a one text box search, and one button,when i add the text and click button, related data will be getting but when i click another search.that is taking same id,previous id not clearing. how to clear that id

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">


    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>

    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbncollegeid" data-ng-model="isbncollege" placeholder=" Search By college ISBN" name="isbncollegeid">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="bookcollgeIsbn" name="bookcollgeIsbn" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sky" id="IsbntcolDetails" data-ng-disabled="LibraryIsbnForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="DetailscolByISBN()">Get Details<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sky" id="clear" data-ng-click="ClearISbnCollege()">Clear<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the code to question

Comment: please put some code, you have done so far for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement Search function using Javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031369/how-to-implement-search-function-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @Mr.Bruno it is not necessary the question is related to specific search feature

Comment: `id` should be unique in entire page

Comment: Could you please post the content of `DetailscolByISBN`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line of code after getting results in `javascript`:

```
document.getElementById('elementid').value = "";
```

in `Jquery`:

```
$('#elementid').val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ClearISbnCollege` just make `isbncollege` model empty

```
$scope.ClearISbnCollege = function() {
    $scope.isbncollege = "";
}
```

When you will click the **Clear** button, input will be emptied.